# Proving: if P then (if p then q) without dependencies (How Logic Works Exercise 3.2.3)

Tags: logic

I am working through Hans Halvorson's How Logic Works: A User's Guide and I am struggling to solve Exercise 3.2.2 which reads:

Prove the following sequent: ⊢ Q → (P → Q)

My proposed solution using the rules Halvorson has thus far presented(namely: conjunction elimination/introduction, disjunction intro, modus ponens, modus tollens, double negation, and conditional proof) :

1   (1) Q → (P → Q) a

2   (2) Q           a

1,2 (3) P → Q       1,2 MP

1   (4) Q → (P → Q) 2,3 CP

(5) (Q → (P → Q)) → (Q → (P → Q)) 1,4 CP

The use of a conditional proof (CP) on line 5 seems off to me and obviously the statement (Q → (P → Q)) → (Q → (P → Q)) ≠ ⊢ Q → (P → Q).

Any guidance on how to use CP more appropriately would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to make a truth table?

Comment: Yes, I am expressly trying to avoid proof via truth table. Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you would add the rules that are available to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the specific rules you have available it's quite difficult to give you an answer that fits those rules  Anyway, here's a few ways and hopefully you can fit them to your system.

Augmentation Method
$\begin{array}{}
\{1\}&1.&Q&\text{A for CP}\\
\{2\}&2.&P&\text{A for CP}\\
\{1, 2\}&3.&P\land Q&\text{1, 2 $\land$I}\\
\{1, 2\}&4.&Q&\text{3 $\land$E}\\
\{1\}&5.&P\to Q&\text{2, 4 CP}\\
\{\}&6.&Q\to (P\to Q)&\text{1, 5 CP}\\
\end{array}$

Reiteration Method
$\begin{array}{}
\{1\}&1.&Q&\text{A for CP}\\
\{2\}&2.&P&\text{A for CP}\\
\{1, 2\}&3.&Q&\text{1, 2 Reit}\\
\{1\}&4.&P\to Q&\text{2, 3 CP}\\
\{\}&5.&Q\to (P\to Q)&\text{1, 4 CP}\\
\end{array}$

Derived Rule Method
$\begin{array}{}
\{1\}&1.&Q&\text{A for CP}\\
\{1\}&2.&P\to Q&\text{1 DR}\\
\{\}&3.&Q\to (P\to Q)&\text{1, 2 CP}\\
\end{array}$

I've included this because it's a really common derived rule and it's really quite a handy one to know (the proof should be obvious).

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The author of HLW states the CP rule as follows: if G => B, then G - {A} => A -> B. (Exercise: think why such a rule is sound, using truth tables.) Thus, the following proof is valid:

1  (1) Q       a

2  (2) P      a

1  (3) P -> Q  2,1 CP

(4) Q -> (P -> Q)  1,3 CP

The system of HLW has no reiteration rule, since such a rule has no natural implementation in a sequent calculus. If one wants to block reiteration-like maneuvers, there would need to be a more sophisticated way of handling dependency numbers.

Comment: I'm afraid line 3 is incorrect. Have a look again at conditional proofs and you'll see what you're missing

Comment: I did write the rule myself in How Logic Works, and line 3 is a correct application of CP. In the system of this book, it is not required that the assumption (on line 2) is actually used in the derivation of the conclusion (on line 1).

Comment: IMO, it's a terrible idea to obfuscate augmentation/reiteration. Not only does it have some philosophical importance, there are logics students will come across in their studies that deny its use. However, if you edit your post with the CP rule you're using, I won't downvote your answer as it may have utility for someone

Answer (score -2):

If $P = T, Q = T$, then $Q \to (P \to Q)=T$. If $P = T, Q = F$, then $Q\to (P\to Q)= F \to F = T$. If $P = F, Q = T$, then $Q\to (P\to Q)=T\to T = T$. Finally, if $P = F, Q = F$, then $Q\to (P\to Q)= F\to T = T$. Thus $Q\to (P\to Q) = T$ for any values of $P, Q$. Hence it is a tautology, proving the claim.

Comment: (-1) The OP is looking for a syntactic proof of this claim, whereas you provided a semantic interpretation. This would be analogous to someone asking for the inverse of a matrix, and someone responding with "the determinant is not 0". Yes, those two things are equivalent, but the former contains more explicit information

Comment: Aside from what @HallaSurvivor has said, it's an unnecessarily long way to prove it. Assume for reductio that $v(Q\to (P\to Q))=0$, thus $v(Q)=1$ and $v(P\to Q)=0$. But if $v(Q)=1$ then $v(P\to Q)=1$ - a contradiction. This proves $\vDash Q\to (P\to Q)$ and $\vdash Q\to (P\to Q)$ follows from completeness.